# My far apart villages are becoming one village

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Note that this is Minecraft Bedrock, the latest non-beta update (as of 4/18/20) which I believe contains everything in 1.15

This question is not a duplicate of other iron golem farm related questions because it uses the updated mechanics and presents a unique problem related to job site blocks and how they define a village.

## My problem

On the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming) it is stated that a village is defined as a radius of 32 blocks from either the village center or the farthest Point of Interest block, whichever is further. This gives a minimum radius of 32 blocks. I have a villager breeder and an iron golem farm both of which are more than 64 blocks apart but they seem to function as one village

#### beds and bells

From the wiki "*A village center is the northwest bottom corner of a point-of-interest (POI) block, which can be a bed pillow or bell, or workstation and bell if there are no beds.*". Given that my iron farm and breeder both have beds, I believe mt village centers are defined by my beds or bells and those centers are more than 64 blocks apart.

#### job site blocks

My farthest job site block in my iron farm is **exactly** 64 blocks away from my farthest job site block in my villager breeder. The beds are even further apart due to the design of the iron farm. Even if I had no beds the centers would still be more than 32 blocks apart and thus should not become the same village because the centers don't come within the 32 block radius of each other. The circles may intersect but neither center should be inside either circle. My understanding is that the circles can overlap, but they only form one blob when both "centers" are within 32 blocks.

#### what I've seen

1. my villager breeder spawns cats whereas my iron farm does not
2. sometimes villagers from the breeder will link to job site blocks on the iron farm.

#### job site linking problems

The wiki says that villagers search a 48 block radius for job site blocks. Given that my breeder villagers are always 64 blocks or more from the job site blocks of the iron farm, I don't know how they're linking.

#### conclusion

My question is why does this happen? Is the wiki correct for the bedrock edition? Is this [that bug where villages expand forever: MCPE-46581](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-46581)? What is the real radius I should take into account when making iron farms and villager breeders? Just how far away can villagers link to job site blocks normally and what should I do to fix this?

## Update

Before fixing anything cats would not spawn at all in either the breeder or the iron farm. Villagers would link to the beds in the breeder or the iron farm

I removed the bell and beds from my breeder and my iron farm still did not work. Cats spawned between the two farms when they should have spawned in the iron farm due to the presence of beds. Villagers still acted the same

Not until I removed the job site blocks at the breeder did the cats finally start spawning in my iron golem farm. Now the villager breeder is effectively removed. The villagers in the breeder suddenly wanted to move to the iron farm despite being more than 64 blocks from it.

Comment: You created one village - and it is honestly hard to get rid of it. Also radius of village is 32+, so smallest one is 64x64. If u have bed on the edge, it increases by 32 from the bed, and village could merge because of that, even when you remove bed later. I think you will have to remove anything "that is village" (except villagers) from breeding site and try to create "new village" there ( - safe distance should be 100 and not 64.) Or try linking villagers to workstation.